# My ajax form doesn't show my post response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Well I've been having this issue now where my ajax form doesn't show my response value which I enter in the text field. I can't seem to understand why it doesn't show my post value at all.

reset.php

```
<html>  
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
function submitdata()
{
 var email=document.getElementById( "emailfield" );
 var datastring='email='+ emailfield;
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "work2.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:datastring
        cache:false
        success: function (html){
            $('#msg').html();
        }
    });
});

      </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
E-mail: <input type="text" id="emailfield"><br>
<input value="submit" type="submit" onclick="return submitdata()">
</form>
<p id="msg"><p/>
</body>
</html>
```

work2.php

```
<?php
$email=$_POST['email'];
echo "response $email";
?>
```

Comment: You aren't preventing the default submit process and your variables don't match

Comment: You have to change `var datastring='email='+ emailfield;` to `var datastring={"email": emailfield}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you are missing here:

**1)** You are NOT getting the value from user.

**Use:**

```
var emailfield = document.getElementById( "emailfield" ).value;
```

**OR simply**

```
$("#emailfield").val();
```

**2)** You are not preventing the default submit process.

**Use:**

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

I went ahead and wrote this for you. Just copy all the file and you'll see it working. Hope it helps!

```
<?php

$data = array();
 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
 $data = $_POST['email'];       
 echo json_encode($data);  
 die();      
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="emailfield"><br>
    <input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<p id="msg"><p/>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    $("form").on("submit", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var emailfield = $("#emailfield").val();
        var email ='email='+ emailfield;

        $.ajax({
            url: "testing.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {email: email},
            success: function (result) {
                alert("result: " + result);
                console.log(result);
                $("#msg").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't take value, it's element object, change here

```
  var emailfield = document.getElementById( "emailfield" ).value;
```

Also put html with value

```
  $('#msg').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
<html>  
<head>
<body>   
E-mail: <input type="text" id="emailfield"><br>
<button type="button">Submit</button>    
<p id="msg"><p/>    
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#emailfield").on("click",function(){
  var value = $("#emailfield").val();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "work2.php",
    data: { email: value }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $('#msg').html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```